# Android Studio 3.1 getting more CPU and Memory utilization

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I just upgraded `Android Studio 3.0.1` to `3.1`

```
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3
```

I noticed that it is utilizing more CPU and Memory. Due to this, it became slow in response. It is irritating me. 
Please give some suggestion to rid of it.